# Updating multiple traces using python and plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to update two traces at a time using the drop down box. I am not understanding how the `args` should be setup.

```
fig = go.Figure()

for col in ['DELIVERED', 'RECEIVED']:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=data.loc[data['ID']==str(x[1]),'DATETIME'],
        y=data.loc[data['ID']==str(x[1]), col],
        visible=True,
        name = col
        )
    )

updatemenu = []
buttons = []

for id in data['ID'].unique():
    buttons.append(
        dict(method='restyle',
             label=id,
             visible=True,
             args=[
                 {
                     'y':[data.loc[data['ID']==str(id), 'RECEIVED']],
                     'x':[data.loc[data['ID']==str(id), 'DATETIME']],
                     'type':'scatter'
                 }, 
                 {
                     'y':[data.loc[data['ID']==str(id), 'DELIVERED']],
                     'x':[data.loc[data['ID']==str(id), 'DATETIME']],
                     'type':'scatter'
                 }, 
                   [0]],
            ),
        )

updatemenu = []
your_menu = dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)

updatemenu[0]['buttons'] = buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive'] = True


fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `args` should be setup according to the `method` since it determines which plotly.js function to use when updating the chart (ie. these args will be passed in to that function).

With `method='restyle'`, `args` should comply with the [`Plotly.restyle`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle) function signature :

> `Plotly.restyle(graphDiv, update [, traceIndices])`

Note that the update object is supplied once. If you omit `traceIndices`, default behavior is to apply to all traces. Now let say you have 5 traces and you want to update only the last two (indices range from 0 to 4 and are assigned according to the order of creation), `args` should look like this :

```
args=[
    {
        'y':[data.loc[data['ID']==str(id), 'RECEIVED']],
        'x':[data.loc[data['ID']==str(id), 'DATETIME']],
        'type':'scatter'
    },
    [3, 4]
]
```